# How to run scheduled tasks in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

Im looking for examples on how to run scheduled tasks in spring. Im currently using xml configuration and spring 3.2. I have found their documentation page for scheduled tasks but would like a more simple example to get started. [Here is a link to the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)

Where do I configure the scheduling beans? I want them to run daily and only one task at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following to your spring xml :

```
<task:annotation-driven/>
```

Create a class :

```
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@Named("funBean")
public class FunBean {

        private static final Logger slf4jLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FunBean.class);

         @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
        public void doSomething() {
            slf4jLogger.info("I am working");
        }

    }
```

This should get you going.You can configure the fun bean definition in your xml file just like any spring bean.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">

    <bean id="worker" class="net.bitegroup.smart.Worker">
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduledTask" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
        <property name="delay" value="1000" />
        <property name="period" value="2000" />
        <property name="runnable" ref="worker" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="scheduledThread" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean">
        <property name="scheduledExecutorTasks" ref="scheduledTask" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```